# What would be the Informix SQL for the following problem?

Tags: sql, date, informix, duration

I have a table with two columns the second having dates sorted. I have to generate a third column on differences between dates on the second columns as shown.

```
Ind        Dt_event      duration 
A          31/12/2018      0
A          31/12/2018     26 
A          26/01/2019      4
A          30/01/2019      0
A          30/01/2019     11
A          10/02/2019 
....
```

What is the SQL (INFORMIX) instruction to solve that problem?

Comment: Note that it helps to specify which version of Informix you are using.  Also note that version 11.70 has been out of service since October 2020.  You should be aiming to upgrade to version 14.10 — or at minimum version 12.10.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lead()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_14.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1513.htm):

```
select t.*,
       (lead(dt_event) over (partition by ind order by dt_event) -
        dt_event
       ) as diff
from t;
```

In older versions of Informix, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       ((select min(t2.dt_event)
         from t t2
         where t2.ind = t.ind and t2.dt_event > t.dt_event
        ) -
        dt_event
       ) as diff
from t;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm using an older version (IDS 11.70) which I think does not support the lead function. Any SQL alternative ?

Comment: By the way, I've tryed the coreekated subquery which is supposed to work on IDS11.70 but, I'm not getting the 0 when I have successive date of the same value on  column dt_events. When following dates are equal, I shoul have 0, until the date changes.

Comment: @hmoukouri . . . You need a unique id for each row if you want to handle ties on the date.